# Transparent ActionBar: dynamically change color of back button to make it contrast to background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an application with  trasparent Action Bar. Action Bar has one button - grey back arrow.

Under Action Bar there  is  big ImageView  that shows the picture  downloaded from web. And in case of this downloaded image is also grey, it is very hard to see grey arrow on  transparent action bar.

[image]

Is it some way to pick the  color  from downloaded image and dynamically change back button color to contrast one?

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: You downloading some image and according to that image color you have to change the back arrow color. Am i understood correctly?

Comment: yes, you've  understood  corretly: color of  back  arrow  should  adapt  to  color  of downloaded image

Comment: Take a look at the [Palette API](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html).